# Padding/margin in repeating table print css

Tags: css, printing

A repeating table with thead/tbody works fine. When I add a tfoot it works great for all pages but last page. Here, the tfoot is not printed at bottom. but after the last element in tbody. I solved this by making tfood

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

Problem here is that on pages where content is full height in tbody, the content will overlap the tfoot. See image below. I have tried adding padding to @page and body, tr and td, I have tried margin and negative margin on tbody, tfoot but nothing works.

Does any one have an idea of how to add margin/padding to make sure there is 1cm of space between the repeating content in tbody -> tr -> td and the fixed tfoot?

[image: Overlapping tfoot/tbody]

Comment: A tfoot is a table footer so of course it prints at the end of the table. You possibly want a page footer.

Comment: That I understand. However, even if I make it as a div apart from the table, the table will overflow the footer. I need padding/margin per page on the tbody, I cannot figure out how